# RedHat server not booting: "The superblock could not be read"

Tags: linux, redhat, ext3, fsck

After restarting a RedHat server, it fails to boot into the operating system. It says "an error occurred during the file system check". After doing a `fsck`, it says

> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2 filesystem

[image: Screenshot]

What should I do?

Comment: yes it says device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdg2 (my partition)

Comment: What is the output of `lvs`?

Answer (score 2):

Find a backup of superblock with appropriate utility (like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)).
Then execute the following:

```
fsck.ext2 -b $SUPERBLOCK_POSITION -B $BLOCK_SIZE /dev/sdg2
```

where *$SUPERBLOCK_POSITION* and *$BLOCK_SIZE* are taken from TestDisk.
*/dev/sdg2* - partition with corrutped superblock

Comment: i read somewhere that testDisk can erase all your files. never used it. How true is that please?

Comment: I've not got such info regarding TestDisk. You can als try "dumpe2fs /dev/sdg2 | grep -i superblock"

Comment: the "dumpe2fs /dev/sdg2 | grep -i superblock" has shown some BLOCK_SIZE but it retuns that device or resource busy while trying to open. i have a question to ask, What is the correct partition to run the command on? May be I have been doing it wrongly.

Comment: @OlumideAlabi you could do anything you want to your disk data, but the suggested answer has the appropriate command found quite easily.